# what is the advantages using mysqli_free_result()?

Tags: php, mysqli

It is essential  to used this function. what will happen using this? can it will improve execution time and speedup my website?

Comment: See also [What is the advantage of using `mysqli_free_result`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088155/mysqli-free-result-necessary)

Comment: Mainly, `mysqli_free_result()` is useful if you intend to make multiple SELECT queries. PHP's garbage collection will free them when they are no longer needed, but you may free them explicitly earlier if you need to manage memory usage more carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mysqli_free_result() function frees the memory associated with the result.

Thus, it's for the system's health and potentially avoid memory-related problem and thus provide better performance.