# mysqli_fetch_object(): Couldn't fetch mysqli_result in

Tags: php, mysqli

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$product_id = $_GET['id'];

if($connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','accounting')){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE product_id='$product_id'";
    $query = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
    mysqli_free_result($query);
    mysqli_close($connect);
}else{
print "Connection failed";
}

while ( $fetch = mysqli_fetch_object($query) ) {
    print $fetch->id;
}

?>
```

i don't know why my code doesn't work !, it seems correct.
help me guys :)

Comment: *help me guys* won't help you fetch answers...

Comment: There could be a multitude of problems: bad credentials, bad query syntax, querying for columns that don't exist, invalid/non-existent "`product_id`", improperly installed PHP, or maybe the fact that there's **no such function as [`mysqli_free_result()`](http://us2.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=mysqli_free_result&scope=quickref)**. Without more context, nobody here could _possibly_ know what your specific problem is.

Comment: @esqew Apparently there is http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- I stand corrected. I wonder why it doesn't show up in a search of the manual.

Comment: @esqew I wondered that too, till I found it in an SO question http://stackoverflow.com/q/14088155/ via Google.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hmph. Manual bug? Maybe I'll submit something.

Comment: @esqew I thought that also, 2nd Google entry found is a link to http://www.php.net/mysqli_free_result and the 3rd being http://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php when Googling "mysqli_free_result". Oh well.

Comment: Do `var_dump($product_id);` placed under `$product_id = $_GET['id'];` and `var_dump($sql);` after your query, see what that echos out. Plus, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if that yields any errors.

Comment: @Fred-ii- not to clog up this comment thread anymore, but I [put in a bug for this](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67527).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysqli_free_result($query);
```

This discards the result, so it shouldn't be a surprise that you can't fetch from it *after* you free it!

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php says:

> You should always free your result with mysqli_free_result(), **when your result object is not needed anymore.**

(emphasis mine)

Move the call to mysqli_free_result() to after your while loop is done.