# Is it necessary to use mysqli_free_result?

Tags: php, mysqli

I would like to know if it is necessary to use `mysqli_free_result()`?
and what would happen if do not use it?

In the MySQL version, it wasn't introduced and we had no problem back then

Answer (score 0):

It's not really neccesary but it would be good practice. It isn't too much effort to add in that one line. Also, this question is a duplicate from [mysqli_free_result necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088155/mysqli-free-result-necessary)

Comment: I'm just going to piggy back on what @Storm Epke mentioned - it's good practice to do it because it causes you to think on managing resources and memory which can become even more important in other programming languages.